# Why does SurfaceFlinger render layers upside down

Tags: android, surfaceflinger

Recently, when digging into the `SurfaceFlinger` code, I discovered it renders its layers upside down, using the method like 1.0f minus vertex Y coordinate.
 I feel confused. Why do they do this?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because OpenGL's (0,0) point is at the bottom-left of the screen.. whereas the higher-level windowing API assumes (0,0) is the top-left.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the answer.